# RAID disk size is slightly more than 500

Tags: hardware-raid, raid1

In my shop we have a number of Windows 7 machines from HP which have hardware RAID 1.  Some of them have Hitachi HDS721050CLA662 disks rated at 500.1 GB.  If I have to replace one of these disks due to a failure, will a generic "500 GB" disk do?  Or is it the case that, because of that extra 0.1 GB, I have to use a larger disk size?

Comment: They may need to be blessed by HP, that is to say you may need to buy HP branded drives.